# Avoid an inner .ToList() in a LINQ query?

Tags: c#, performance, linq

I am building a method that takes a `List<T>` and turns it into a `DataTabe`.  In the process, I want to filter out any properties that are tagged with the `[NotMapped]` attribute.

I have the entire method working, but I am a bit worried about one part of it... the part that weeds out the `[NotMapped]` properties.  Here's what I've got:

```
    public static DataTable CreateDataTable<T>(IEnumerable<T> list)
    {
        Type type = typeof(T);

        var properties = type.GetProperties().Where(p =>
                        p.CustomAttributes.ToList().Count == 0 ||
                        (p.CustomAttributes.ToList().Count > 0 && p.CustomAttributes.ToList()[0].AttributeType.Name != "NotMappedAttribute")
                        ).ToList();

        // Rest of the method...
    }
```

So, that works as I'd like it to and gets rid of anything that looks like this (for example) so it doesn't end up in the final `DataTable`:

```
    [NotMapped]
    public string Description { get; set; }
```

My concern is about performance and just general best practice. The `var properties =` LINQ query seems clumsy to me, but I'm not seeing a more efficient way to improve it.

Namely, I don't like calling `p.CustomAttributes.ToList()` 3 times.  Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: You have more than just a performance problem.  If the "NotMapped" attribute isn't the first attribute you're mapping it.  That's wrong.  Also you should really check against your specific type, not just any type with that name.

Comment: @Servy, yes, very good point. I'm aware of that. I'll worry about that after I fix the overall query!

Comment: Performance is irrelevant when the behavior is wrong.  Get the correct behavior *first*.  Then optimize if needed.

Comment: ok, point taken.  I will modify and re-post.  In the meantime, any other advice is welcome!

Comment: Why not use `p.GetCustomAttribute<NotMappedAttribute>() != null`?

Comment: Unless you actually need the attribute, what @Amy commented should be the best way

Comment: @Amy!  This is looking positive. See my edit in the OP.

Comment: @CaseyCrookston Re your edit: you are missing the method call with parenthesis: `GetCustomAttribute<NotMappedAttribute>()`

Comment: In fairness to the OP, my original comment left out the parenthesis.  I added them in a quick edit that wasn't quick enough.

Comment: Ah!  I should have spotted that myself. Testing :)

Comment: ...also, I'm pretty sure that condition should be reversed, since you want properties _without_ the listed attribute.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse, right!  It needs to be `p.GetCustomAttribute<NotMappedAttribute>() == null`

Comment: Now I just need an answer for me to mark :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer the original question, you can avoid calling `ToList()` multiple times by saving its return value:

```
type.GetProperties().Where(p =>
                    p.CustomAttributes.ToList().Count == 0 ||
                    (p.CustomAttributes.ToList().Count > 0 && p.CustomAttributes.ToList()[0].AttributeType.Name != "NotMappedAttribute")
                    )
```

... becomes...

```
type.GetProperties().Where(p => 
{
    var attrs = p.CustomAttributes.List();
    return attrs.Count == 0 || (attrs.Count > 0 && attrs[0].AttributeType.Name != "NotMappedAttribute");
})
```

**However**, I recommend instead doing this:

```
type.GetProperties().Where(p => p.GetCustomAttribute<NotMappedAttribute>() == null))
```

Its shorter and easier to understand at a glance.

Answer (score 3):

```
private IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> GetPropertiesWithoutAttribute<TAttribute>(Type type) 
    where TAttribute : Attribute
{
    return type.GetProperties().Where(p => !p.GetCustomAttributes<TAttribute>().Any());
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  This also works, but is a bit more than what I need, at least for now. If we need to allow for other attributes in the future, we'll go this route.